# Overwritting properties files

Tags: java, properties

Is there a way to overwrite just one field in a properties file with Java?

For example if my app.properties looks like

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=user1
```

and I want to change it to

```
dbpassword=password
database=localhost
dbuser=user2
```

with just one setProperty command, i.e. without having to overwrite my other fields, can I do it? I tried the following:

```
prop.setProperty("dbuser", "user2");

prop.store(new FileOutputStream("app.properties",true), null);
```

but it just appends the property to the file and doesn't overwrite the existing dbuser field.

Comment: Well if you just want to read again from the properties file... this will work eventually; as in the appended file the last value will be used. Having said that I believe this is not what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to protect the data??

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("app.properties",false), null);
```

Instead.  Basically you were asking the `FileOutputStream` to append the results to the existing file, rather then overwriting it

Comment: If i do that my other fields will disappear as the properties file will get overwritten and now there is only one property that is being set before writing to the file.

Comment: First read from the property file into the prop object. overwride the variable and then store it... *Note : it will remove all comments and spaces. IMHO do it manually thats what property files are for.

Answer (score -1):

```
The  example, PropertiesTest, creates a Properties object and initializes it from myProperties.txt .

subliminal.message = Buy StayPuft Marshmallows!
PropertiesTest then uses System.setProperties to install the new Properties objects as the current set of system properties.


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {

        // set up new properties object
        // from file "myProperties.txt"

        Properties p =
            new Properties(System.getProperties());
        p.load(propFile);

        // set the system properties
        System.setProperties(p);
        // display new properties
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
Note how PropertiesTest creates the Properties object, p, which is used as the argument to setProperties:

Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
```